# Pass Table Data to Drop Down Lists Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code, a table

```
        <table id="namedConsultants" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Consultant</th>
                    <th>Days Assigned</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConID" name="ConID" readonly="true" type="hidden" value="4" /></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConFullName" name="ConFullName" readonly="true" type="text" value="Person A" /></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConTimeAssigned" name="ConTimeAssigned" readonly="true" type="text" value="1.0" /></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editConsultant">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConID" name="ConID" readonly="true" type="hidden" value="2" /></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConFullName" name="ConFullName" readonly="true" type="text" value="Person B" /></td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" id="ConTimeAssigned" name="ConTimeAssigned" readonly="true" type="text" value="1.0" /></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editConsultant">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I need to be able to click the 'Edit' link beside each table row and then have the **ConFullName** and **ConTimeAssigned** passed to two drop down lists

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ConsultantID must be a number." id="ConsultantID" name="ConsultantID">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field daysAssigned must be a number." id="daysAssigned" name="daysAssigned">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Once the 'Edit' link it clicked beside each table row, I would like to call a JQuery function like this which would then pass the data to the appropriate drop down lists.

```
$("#namedConsultants").on('click', '.editConsultant', function () {

    //alert("test");
    //Get ConFullName and ConTimeAssigned and pass them to the two drop down lists

});
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to pass this data using my JQuery function?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**

Removed repeating IDs as requested

```
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="ConID" class="form-control" readonly value="2" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ConFullName" class="form-control" readonly value="Person A" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="ConTimeAssigned" class="form-control" readonly value="1.0" /></td>
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="editConsultant">Edit</a></td>
</tr>
```

Updated JQuery function

```
$("#namedConsultants").on('click', '.editConsultant', function () {

    //alert("test");
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var name = tr.find("input.ConFullName").val();
    var timeAssigned = tr.find("input.ConTimeAssigned").val();

    alert(name);
    alert(timeAssigned);

    //$("#ConsultantID").val(name);
    //$("#daysAssigned").val(timeAssigned);


});
```

Comment: note first of all that id's have to be unique or you will experience errors when accessing those elements using their id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have repeating ID's in your table, that is bad, ID's **must** be unique! Give those `inputs` your wish to target a class and then use an instance of `this`

```
$("#namedConsultants").on('click', '.editConsultant', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var name = tr.find("input.ConFullName").val();
    var timeAssigned = tr.find("input.ConTimeAssigned").val();

    //Append values to whichever dropdown you wish
});
```

I assumed you would change your repeating ID's to classes in the code above

Edit: Using `name` attributes:

```
$("#namedConsultants").on('click', '.editConsultant', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var name = tr.find("input[name=ConFullName]").val();
    var timeAssigned = tr.find("input[name=ConTimeAssigned]").val();

    //Append values to whichever dropdown you wish
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see my updated question. Unfortunately I still can't get the data from my table passed to the drop down lists. Currently, the variables 'name' and 'timeAssigned' are not passed any data when the Edit link it clicked. Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: @tgriffiths -- Read the last part of my answer, it assumed you would use classes. You're now using a `name` attribute - so your selectors would be `input[name=ConTimeAssigned]` and so on.